# Rate of change in size: Moving Objects

Tags: kinematics, geometry

Is there a way of calculating the rate at which an object decreases/increases in size relative to the observer. For example, if a bus(4m wide) is moving away from a stationary observer at the rate of 20m/s(assuming a constant velocity and a zero gradient on the road), how long will it take for the bus to appear like it's half the size? Or at what rate does the bus 'decrease' in size relative to the observer?

Comment: Are you interested in the theory of relativity? If not, I don't understand your question

Comment: I wasn't strictly referring to the theory of relativity,but how moving objects generally appear to change in size as they move away from observers.If you can explain it in relativistic terms also,it would be great.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about apparent size, correct?

For every doubling of the distance, the apparent size is halved, so the starting distance is important.  If the bus starts 20m away, and moves away at 20m per second:

```
Time 0 - Distance 20 - Apparent Size 100%
Time 1 - Distance 40 - Apparent Size 50%
Time 3 - Distance 80 - Apparent Size 25%
Time 7 - Distance 160 - Apparent Size 12.5%
```

and so on.

If you wanted a formula, it would be something like:
*Apparent Size = Initial Size x (Initial Distance / Current Distance)*

Note that 'size' here is all relative; you're really measuring how much of your field of vision something takes up.

Comment: Yes,I did mean apparent size.That answered my question clearly.Thanks!